# Why is my tooltip not remaining visible on mouseover? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I'm trying to get a tooltip to remain visible on mouseover. It works when you mouseover the first time. But try to mouseout, then mouseover another link and mouseover that tooltip. It will fade.

Check out the code on jsFiddle. Would love to know what I'm doing wrong here.

http://jsfiddle.net/6FpM8/7/

Comment: not sure what you mean, seems to work fine for me

Comment: no it is not working. He would like to keep tooltip when is hovered and it fade. not just hover link ... try again.

Comment: It is most definitely not working correctly for me. Have you tried mousing over one link briefly (not so long that the tooltip appears), then mousing another, then over the tooltip itself? Sometimes it disappears, sometimes it doesn't. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: yea .. it is not working in opera, ie and firefox too

Comment: @Will, when you edited to say the "original" code, do you mean not the original link but before any revisions? If so, that's not at all the code I'm asking about. Rolled back ftm.

Comment: @Josh my bad, deleted a comment-answer; I mistakenly thought it was you that made it, so I merged the comment into your question.

Comment: @Will ah, I see. No problem! Was just a wee bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little late for you but for others who may land here. Use [version from github](https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy/zipball/v1.0.0a). Then for title parameter of the plugin use this callback function

```
$('.tooltip').tipsy({ html:true, delayOut:2000, title: function(){
        $('.tipsy').hide();
        return this.getAttribute('original-title');
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you link to the version of the plugin yo are talking about?

Comment: @Spycho: I got it from here - https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy/zipball/v1.0.0a. Used it today morning and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

i know this is an oldish issue, but you could either change the `delayOut` option via either

`$(".id of tooltip").tipsy({delayOut: "length of time" });`

or you could change it in tipsy's js.

Alternately, you could change the leave function in the js to suit your need.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. The problem's still not solved, and unfortunately `delayOut` does not do what I want. I'm trying to keep the tooltip up even when you hover over the tooltip itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a class="mylink" id="1" href="#" title="hey" >Test</a>
<a class="mylink" id="2" href="#" title="hey" >Test</a>
<a class="mylink" id="3" href="#" title="hey" >Test</a>
```

Just set the title via the html tag and not the JS, that worked in my Fire Fox.

Comment: I'm not sure this is answering the question.

Comment: Im just saying that setting the title within the html tag rather than with your javascript fixed it. It was working perfectly for me.